# Converting pointer to string and send as char array not working properly

Tags: java, c++, pointers, char, send

I have a problem with sending directory names over socket from my C++ client, to my Java server.

Sending ordinary messages like "hello world", works great , but the following doesn't and I can not figure out what the problem is:

```
char const * files = ffd.cFileName; // get directory name

            string str(files, 0, strlen(files)); // convert pointer to string, right?

            char mess[str.size()];
            strcpy(mess, str.c_str()); // make char array :)

            cout << "Send file: " << mess << " with strlen: " << strlen(mess) << " and sizeof: " << sizeof(mess) << endl;

            int sent = 0;
            if ((sent = send(connectSocket, mess, sizeof(mess), 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                closesocket(connectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                connectToServer();
            }
```

The java server just receives the directory names like this:

```
wam
p
Win
dow
s
Win
dow
s.o
ld
wxW
idg
ets
```

I can not understand what I'm missing because I have tried every possible way to do this and the C++ client prints like:

"Send file: windows with strlen: 7 and sizeof: 7"

I do not think that the java server is the problem since I can receive normal strings and messages perfectly, but anyway here is the JAVA code:

```
is = socket.getInputStream();
byteArray = new byteArray[1024]; 
    while (true) {
                c = is.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                String recv = new String(byteArray, 0, c);
                System.out.println(recv);
                if (recv.equals("<EOF>")){
                    break;
                }
                list.add(recv);
            }
```

If you request something else or anything just leave a comment and I will fix it.

Comment: Note that `mess` contains `str.size()` bytes, and then you write `str.size() + 1` bytes to it.

Comment: How are you sending "ordinary messages like Hello World"?

Comment: string str = "hello"; char mess[str.size()];
    strcpy(mess, str.c_str()); and the same send method

Comment: @immibis what do you mean with write +1?

Comment: @Johan how many bytes does strcpy write?

Comment: Also, what does `send` return?

Comment: @immibis I don't know, Im new to c++. studying java

Comment: @immibis send returns the same as sizeof, so if the sizeof is 7, send is 7 too, that's why this is so weird

Comment: @Johan how do you know it returns 7?

Comment: @Johan Also, a C-style string has (the length) + 1 bytes. It has one byte per character, then a 0 byte at the end.

Comment: Please show us the client part. I strongly suspect some undefined behavior (like reading much more than the 7 chars in the  array).

Comment: @iKiWiXz Hello! this is the client part, the whole program is pretty big. Funny that you mention undefined behaviour because after the while loop when it has fetched all the directories and sent them, I end with this sendToServer("<EOF>");    and the last message gets split up too!, but when the client connects it send "windows8", and that works good!

Comment: `string str(files, 0, strlen(files));` can be simplified to `string str(ffd.cFileName);` if it cFileName is a null-terminated string.

Comment: Also, instead of creating an unnecessary character buffer `mess`, just change your send call to `send(connectSocket, str.c_str(), str.length(), 0)`

Comment: @AtlasC1 I simplified it as you told me but now the int sent returns 0?! but the java server keeps receiving the strings in parts of 3

Comment: @AtlasC1 Whatever I do in the client part, the java server keeps splitting them, what is happening on the way from client to server? why would java split them?

Comment: It is being split on your server, because TCP is stream-based. `is.read()` is reaching the end of its internal receive buffer before the client has finished sending its complete message, so it prints only what it has received up to that point.

Comment: @AtlasC1 I solved it (check answer) but I want to thank you anyway, you and clicquot the dog, both led me on the right way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, Just added `byteArray = new byte[1024];` and now it works:

```
         while (true) {
            byteArray = new byte[1024]; // I ADDED THIS AND NOW THE JAVA SERVER RECEIVES IT CORRECTLY!

            c = is.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            recv = new String(byteArray, 0, c);


            System.out.println(recv);
            if (recv.equals("<EOF>")){
                break;
            }
            list.add(recv);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Question: are you sending via TCP or UDP? I'm guessing TCP, and if that is the case, you need to treat the socket as more of a stream. That stream may get broken up into a bunch of packets - you don't really control that. What I might do is to prefix the string length of each directory (ex, 3foo, 4barz, etc), read from the socket and determine what constitutes as a logical block or string, and then assemble / print the strings based on that. If you go with that route, you need to track how much you read each time until you think you are done.

Comment: Yes I'm using TCP. But how is that possible, I can send anything like "hello world!!!!" but not when I try to convert pointer. how/why would it get broken up into bunch of packets? I'm not good at c++, studying Java and learning c++ on the side.

Comment: Here's some info on TCP https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~l38613dw/website_spring_03/readings/IntroToTCPIP.html which covers some info on the packet splitting, and here's some info on reassembling packets https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectReassemble.html on how to reassemble split packets. Google is your friend :)

Comment: I solved it but you and  atlas both led me on the right way! 1+ for great info too! thanks.